# Is it possible for me type recover my browsing history and bookmarks after resting Firefox on Windows XP?

Tags: firefox

I use Windows XP and I just reset Firefox to factory settings and now *all* of my browsing history and bookmarks are gone. Can I fix this and get my bookmarks and browsing history back?

Comment: If you have a backup of your user directory from before you refreshed Firefox, you could restore that and then not redo the refresh.

Comment: you shouldn't even expose an XP PC to the internet

Comment: Firefox also [ended supported XP long time ago](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/end-support-windows-xp-and-vista). And maybe the Firefox server will also refuse to serve old versions of Firefox and you won't be able to sync anymore

Comment: Basically, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

#### It depends

Once you reset Firefox to "factory settings", your personal data, including history and bookmarks are deleted (that's the point, indeed).

You may still be able to recover your data if:

1. You created a [Firefox account](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/accounts/) and enabled [synchronisation of your data](https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox/sync-and-save)
2. You have a backup of your user folder (you should alway have a backup, at least one), including your [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox)

If at least you  met one of the above requirements the answer is

#### YES, you can

In the first case, it should be able to login using the same account and wait some time for the data to restore from Mozilla servers.

In the second case, you should find your profile directory from the backup, and restore it in its original place.

---

Instead if you didn't enable Firefox Sync, neither have a working backup, the answer is

#### NO, your data is gone

And unfortunately there's nothing you can do about it.

---

*(Actually, there is a tiny tiny chance to recover that data using esoteric data recovery tools such as [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and a good knowledge of the format of the files you're trying to recover. This way in some really lucky cases, one could be able recover some of the data from the disk)*

Answer (score 1):

## No

As you  said, you reset Firefox to factory settings and unless you have a backup (which you probably don't since you wouldn't be asking this question) you have no way of getting those bookmarks back unless you are willing to do digital forensics on your drives (which would be useless if you didn't stop using your computer immediately to prevent the necessary data from being overwritten).